# Removing self intersecting poly-lines programatically

Tags: python, polyline

Consider the following...

[image]

Given an ordered array of vertices

> [ [1.11, 2.22], [4.44, 3.33], [5.55, 6.66] ...]

where each vertex is an x,y coordinate represented like (x = 11.11, y = 2.22) on a plane and the array as a whole represents a poly-line. What is the fastest way in Python to detect self intersection and remove the "knot" in a "knotted" line so that the following is a result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the problem is vague. It would be helpful to understand what you define as "knot". What I understand is that you want to: 
1. Find the first and last intersections in the poly-line.
2. Get the part [Vn, first intersection] and [last intersection, V+5] and form a polyline out of them.

You could use the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) to detect all intersections and sort them, then do the rest.

Best regards